# Python: Add value to a list at predefined indexes

Tags: python, list

I have a list (aList)
I need to create another list of the same length as aList (checkColumn) and add 1 at the positions defined in the index list (indexList), the positions not defined in the indexList should be 0

> Input:

```
aList = [70, 2, 4, 45, 7 , 55, 61, 45]
indexList = [0, 5, 1]
```

> Desired Output:

```
checkColumn = [1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

I have been experimenting around with the following code, but I get the output as [1,1]

```
for a in len(aList):
    if a == indexList[a]:
        checkColumn = checkColumn[:a] + [1] + checkColumn[a:]
    else:
        checkColumn = checkColumn[:a] + [0] + checkColumn[a:]
```

I have tried with checkColumn.insert(a, 1) and I get the same result.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can I ask why do you need this exactly? Can you describe the problem that led to this solution?

Comment: aList is the id of all items, of these I have already identified the indexes of the bad items and put it in indexList. Now I want to mark in another list (check) the items that are bad (1) and those good (0)

Comment: This re-describes the problem you've presented. Not how it spawned. I think there may be a simpler solution to what you're doing on a higher-level.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this help?

First, you initialize checkColumn with 0

```
checkColumn = [0] * len(aList)
```

Then, loop through indexList and update the checkColumn

```
for idx in indexList:
    checkColumn[idx] = 1
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in one line using a list comprehension:

```
aList = [70, 2, 4, 45, 7 , 55, 61, 45]
indexList = [0, 5, 1]

checkColumn = [1 if a in indexList else 0 for a in range(len(aList))]
print(checkColumn)
# [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You can make in even shorter with `int(a in indexList)`